# Animating Bootstrap 5 dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations, bootstrap-5

I am attempting to animate a right-aligned Bootstrap dropdown with CSS and am not able to get it working. I thought by setting the `transition` property to apply to the element's `width` property it would work, but it does not.

I can see the width of the element is initially set to 0 in my browser inspector, and is set to "auto" after the menu is made visible. I can see the transition getting applied if I adjust the width manually, but for some reason it won't happen when the menu is shown. I've tried using pixel values instead of "auto" with no change.

I'm expecting to see the menu "slide out" to the right at the same rate as the menu button rotates. Is this possible?

```css
div.dropdown > .btn {
    transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0,-0.14,.27,1.55);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

div.dropdown > .btn.show {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}

div.dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
    transition: width 0.8s cubic-bezier(0,-0.14,.27,1.55);
    width: 0;
}

div.dropdown > .btn.show + .dropdown-menu {
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown dropend p-4">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        ++
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this solution.
Animation in transition is your own.

```css
div.dropdown > .btn {
    transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0,-0.14,.27,1.55);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

div.dropdown > .btn.show {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}

div.dropdown>.dropdown-menu {    
    display: inherit;
    transform: translate(69px, 19px) scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0,-0.14,.27,1.55);
    transform-origin:left;
    left: 0;
}

div.dropdown>.btn.show+.dropdown-menu {
    display: inherit;
    transform: translate(69px, 19px) scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown dropend p-4">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        ++
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Fixed for firefox

```
div.dropdown>.btn.show+.dropdown-menu {
    display: inherit;
    transform: translate(69px, 19px) scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: `transform: translate(69px, 19px) scaleX(0);` Where did these values come from?

Comment: Bootstrap adds `transform: translate(69px, 19px)` with a style inline; nedd to fix the dropdown posistion. `scaleX(0)` is for horizontal transition, from 0 to 1.

Comment: I'm only seeing animation when it contracts, not when it expands

Comment: FIxed firefox transition. Try it.

Comment: +1 for effort, and it works in Firefox now. But the translation on the menu div is not a fixed amount, it depends on the content of the button.